# VS Code intellisense not working on a typescript Next.js project with Jest and Cypress, but tests run just fine

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jestjs, cypress, intellisense

I am trying to set up a new repository to start a new project using Next.js with typescript, using both Jest and Cypress and it works fine, my tests all pass with no issue, however my VSCode is still indicating some issue, I assume it to be related to intellisense problem?

Problem seen in my Jest test files:
[image: VSCode intellisense error on Jest test file]

Problem seen in my Cypress test files:
[image: VSCode intellisense error on Cypress test file]

I have found similar issues but the solutions didn't seem to work here...

I have followed the instructions on how to make them work together, creating 2 tsconfig.json, one in the root directory, one in the cypress directory.

**./tsconfig.json:**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "incremental": true,
        "types": ["jest", "node", "@types/testing-library__jest-dom"]
    },
    "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "cypress"]
}
```

**./cypress/tsconfig.json:**

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noEmit": true,
        // be explicit about types included
        // to avoid clashing with Jest types
        "types": ["cypress"]
    },
    "include": [
        "../node_modules/cypress",
        "../tsconfig.json",
        "../package.json",
        "./**/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

**./cypress.config.ts:**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';

export default defineConfig({
    e2e: {
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    },
});
```

**./jest.config.ts:**

```
import nextJest from 'next/jest';
// Sync object
const createJestConfig = nextJest({
    // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
    dir: './',
});

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
const customJestConfig = {
    // Add more setup options before each test is run
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/support/setupTests.js'], // if using TypeScript with a baseUrl set to the root directory then you need the below for alias' to work
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/'],
    testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
    modulePathIgnorePatterns: ['cypress'],
};

module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

**./next.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    eslint: {
        dirs: ['pages', 'public', 'styles', 'cypress', '__tests__', 'support'],
    },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

**./package.json:**

```
{
    "name": "front-end-base-repo",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start",
        "lint": "next lint",
        "lint:fix": "next lint --fix",
        "format": "prettier --write .",
        "prepare": "husky install",
        "precommit": "lint-staged",
        "cy:open": "cypress open",
        "cy:run": "cypress run",
        "test:cy": "start-server-and-test start http://localhost:3000 cy:run",
        "test:jest": "jest --watch",
        "test:jest:ci": "jest --ci"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "next": "12.1.6",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "18.2.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
        "@types/cypress": "^1.1.3",
        "@types/jest": "^28.1.1",
        "@types/node": "18.0.0",
        "@types/react": "18.0.12",
        "@types/react-dom": "18.0.5",
        "@types/testing-library__jest-dom": "^5.14.3",
        "@types/testing-library__react": "^10.2.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.28.0",
        "cypress": "^10.1.0",
        "eslint": "8.17.0",
        "eslint-config-next": "12.1.6",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jest-dom": "^4.0.2",
        "husky": "^8.0.1",
        "jest": "^28.1.1",
        "jest-environment-jsdom": "^28.1.1",
        "lint-staged": "^13.0.1",
        "prettier": "^2.7.0",
        "start-server-and-test": "^1.14.0",
        "ts-node": "^10.8.1",
        "typescript": "4.7.3"
    }
}
```

Here is a [link to the whole repository](https://github.com/MatthieuD134/Base_Next_Project) to check all the configuration, I have tried on another computer and I had the same issue with VSCode showing the error in the editor, but all the tests run fine.

**What I have found so far:**

- Having `/// <reference types="cypress" />` at the top of my cypress tests file seems to solve the issue, but adding `/// <reference types="jest" />` on my jest files doesn't work.
- Having a ./cypress/cypress.d.ts file with a single line `/// <reference types="cypress" />`  solves the issue for cypress tests, VS Code do not show any more errors, but having a similar file for jest ./jest.d.ts or ./**tests**/jest.d.ts with `/// <reference types="jest" />` doesn't solve the issue for my jest files, also tried adding other types like `/// <reference types="@types/testing-library__jest-dom" />`
- Adding `"typeAcquisition": { "include": ["cypress"] }` and
  `"typeAcquisition": { "include": ["jest"] }` to the cypress and jest
  tsconfig.json files doesn't change anything.

**Current State**

I have edited the file at ./cypress/support/e2e.ts to include `/// <reference types="cypress" />` which solves the issue for Cypress test files, but I still got the VSCode errors showing up for Jest test files

Answer (score 1):

For Cypress, add this to `/cypress/support/e2e.ts`, it will effectively give Cypress type info and intellisense to all tests.

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />
```

---

**For problems with Jest `expect`**

Remove `"**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"` from the base tsconfig.json `include` list.
This entry should refer to types not source files.

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...        
    "types": ["jest", "node", "@types/testing-library__jest-dom"]
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "cypress"]
}
```

**index.test.tsx**

```js
expect(heading).toBeInTheDocument(); // intellisense: const expect: jest.Expect
```

Comment: thank you this worked for Cypress, better than putting it in every files, now still gotta figure out how to solve the intellisense issue for jest test files

Comment: So far, I can see the type of `expect` is Chai - maybe this is because Cypress uses Chai?

Comment: yes, I assume it to be the problem. but the code runs fine, meaning that it actually fetches the right type for the `expect` function. Now the question is how to tell VSCode that we're using the Jest's type? I thought the tsconfig files were helping with that

Comment: I got Jest working, had to shut down VS Code and reopen. But I may a lot of changes, so now have to figure out what!

Comment: great! If you find what needs to be modified, please update me

Comment: So, I think the change I made earlier that worked was adding the package [local-cypress](https://github.com/bahmutov/local-cypress), example usage here [local-cypress-and-jest-typescript-example](https://github.com/bahmutov/local-cypress-and-jest-typescript-example). With either local-cypress, or the dummy type defn shown above, you need something in every spec of Jest or Cypress depending on the way you choose to fix it. IMO adding the dummy type as above is the easier or the two fixes.

Comment: adding the line of code doesn't seem to be working for me, it make the test fail for some reason. Having local-cypress installed solved the issue, but may not be the best solution as it's still a work in progress project. Is there a way to explicitly import jest functions like `import {describe, expect, test} from '@jest/globals'` but for extended types?

Comment: Now that you mention it, `let expect` by itself was a bit dumb, obviously makes it `undefined`. Will see about the import.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. It is a good idea to set your computer's path variable.
How to do it:
1)Go to environment variables (search it on your computer)
2)Then go to path
3)Then edit it and add address of your compiler

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it's not clear to me how do I check what compiler I'm using, where it is, and if VSCode offer me several choice of compiler, which one should I be using?

Comment: also, I have only installed Typescript locally, for this specific project. when I had only cypress installed, VSCode wouldn't show any errors, it only appeared after I added Jest.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing a couple things, namely:

1. [typescript transformer](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript) for jest (I recommend [ts-jest](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/) since you already have ts-node).
2. [Configuring](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration) jest to use the transformer

If you go with `ts-jest`, then all you need to do is add the `transform` configuration option:

In **package.json**

```json
"jest": {
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  }
}
```

*OR* In **jest.config.ts**

```
const customJestConfig = {
  preset: 'ts-jest'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've installed `ts-jest` and added the config into my **jest.config.ts** file, but it didn't solve the issue, VSCode still shows the error, even after restarting it